# Really accurate speedometer on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I would like to develop a mobile app for iPhones, that calculates time needed to reach a given velocity. For example: I'm in my car, open the app, choose 100km/h and when I accelerate the app should start to count time and it stops counting just in the moment when I reach 100km/h. It should be very accurate.

I heard about two solutions. First is to use the accelerometer/gyroscope, but some people told me it's bad idea, because I won't be able to calculate time on longer distances. The second option is to use GPS, but on the other hand it can be not as accurate as I want it to be. 
So I need suggestions, which option is better and why.

My targets are iPhones 4s and newer.

Comment: He means iPhone4S and above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more precise than the GPS you will need to have some sort of sensor. Most similar apps and concepts will create a receiver that plugs into the car that the iPhone can connect to. This has the benefit of making all of the sensors in the car available to you. This is an example: https://www.automatic.com/how-automatic-works/